# C# parse JSON group by type

Tags: c#, .net, json, c#-4.0, json.net

This is the JSON

```
[
    {
        "name": "TeamA",
        "zone": "North",
        "id": 12,
        "players": [
            {
                "name": "TAPlayer1",
                "type": "Keeper"
            },
            {
                "name": "TAPlayer2",
                "type": "Bowler"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "TeamB",
        "zone": "South",
        "id": 20,
        "players": [
            {
                "name": "TBPlayer1",
                "type": "Keeper"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "TeamC",
        "zone": "South",
        "id": 45,
        "players": null
    },
    {
        "name": "TeamD",
        "zone": "North",
        "id": 40,
        "players": [
            {
                "name": "Tom",
                "type": "Keeper"
            },
            {
                "name": "Max",
                "type": "Keeper"
            },
            {
                "name": "Sam",
                "type": "Bowler"
            },
            {
                "name": "Jim",
                "type": "Keeper"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I want the result like that (Group by Zone with player type keeper)

```
North
TAPlayer1
Tom
Max

South
TBPlayer1
```

I tried to parse like that

```
public class Player
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class Teams
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string zone { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public List<Player> players { get; set; }
    }
        Teams[] ownersArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Teams[]>(json);
```

I want to display the results group by Zone and type should be keeper. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't use Dynamic for this. If you use dynamic, intellisense can't help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After deserializing the JSON

```
Teams[] teams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Teams[]>(json);
```

you can use LINQ to group by Zone

```
var groupedByZone = teams.Where(t => t.players != null).GroupBy(t => t.zone);
```

From each group we want to get the players

```
var players = groupedByZone.Select(g => new { 
    name = g.Key, 
    players = g.SelectMany(t => t.players).Where(p => p.type == "Keeper").ToArray() 
});
```

This could all be done in one statement

```
var keepersByZone = teams.Where(t => t.players != null)
                         .GroupBy(team => team.zone)
                         .Select(g => new { 
                             name = g.Key, 
                             players = g.SelectMany(team => team.players)
                                        .Where(player => plapyer.type == "Keeper")
                                        .OrderBy(player => player.name)
                                        .ToArray() 
                         });
```

Show output

```
foreach(var zone in keepersByZone) {
    Console.WriteLine(zone.name);
    foreach(var player in zone.players) {
        Console.WriteLine(player.name);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try like his. This will return all  zones, where is any keeper. Maybe helps

```
public class Serilizer
{
  public List<Zone> TeamsInZone(string j)
  {
     var a = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Zone>>(j);
     var list = a.Select(s =>s).Where(t => t.players != null && t.players.Any(u=>u.type == "Keeper")).ToList();
return list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I notice you have the de-serialization step already in place so to display a list of 'keeper' users grouped by zone you will need to use several linq statements. The first step is to get a unique list of 'zones'

```
string[] Zones = (from t in ownersArray select t.zone).Distinct().ToArray();
```

Loop through each zone in the unique list, ouput the zone name. Next find a team within that zone, loop through the team and print each player who is a keeper

```
      foreach (string Zone in Zones) {
            Console.WriteLine("Zone: " + Zone);
            // Find teams in this zone
            Teams[] Ts = (from t in ownersArray where t.zone == Zone select t).ToArray();
            foreach (Teams T in Ts.Where(x=>x.players != null)) {
                foreach (Player P in T.players.Where(x=>x.type == "Keeper").OrderBy(x=>x.name)) {
                    // print players in this zone who are keepers
                    Console.WriteLine(P.name);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: thanks that looks good and what if i want to sort by players alphabetically in each zone?

Comment: Just add .OrderBy(x=>x.name) I've edited the full code

Comment: I am just getting Zones and players are not printing

Comment: I made a spelling mistake, I've updated the code now and all works ok